# JAVA: Running method without running the next line until the method end

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop, joptionpane

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INPUT 1 FOR GAME, ANY FOR EXIT"));
while(x == 1){
    new PokelanzBattle();
    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INPUT 1 FOR GAME, ANY FOR EXIT"));
}
```

In this code, assuming that you entered 1, the while will run.
In the while loop, I want to run PokelanzBattle() method ONLY, but after running it the next line will also be read and run.

How can I run only the method and after I dispose the gui(the gui/method will dispose automatically, with some method inside), the next line will run which is the input dialog box.

Comment: `PokelanzBattle()` is not a method, it is a constructor.

Comment: It already will not run the second line of the `while` loop body until the constructor call returns. What else do you want to happen before running the second line?

Comment: @Dici yes it is a constructor my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be ask for a re-game when your game actually ends.Something like :

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INPUT 1 FOR GAME, ANY FOR EXIT"));
if(x == 1)
   {
    new PokelanzBattle();
   }
```

And when game is over:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("GAME OVER!!! INPUT 1 FOR GAME, ANY FOR EXIT"));
if(x == 1){//....
```